# How to improve the output of text labels around a circle points?

Tags: plotting, labeling, text

```
Table[
    With[{n = t, k = 2}, 
        With[{a = Exp[-2 Pi*I*Range[1., n]/n]}, 
        Graphics@ GraphicsComplex[
                ReIm[I*Join[a, a^k]], 
                {
                    Circle[], 
                    {Red, PointSize -> Medium, Point@Range@n}, 
                    MapThread[Text[#, #, {0, -1.5}, -#2] &, {RotateRight[Range@n, 0], ReIm[-1.5 I*a]}]
                }]
    ]], {t, 7, 30}
]
```

Adapting from a previous post (for which I can't find any more), I'd like to draw some blank circles with equal spaced labeled points like so. As you can see, the postions of numbers are not really ideal.

Is there a way to improve this code, so the numbers around the circle looks nicer? I don't want to change the `RotateRight[Range@n, 0]` for each of them seperately if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Where labels supposed to be placed? Near red points, or between? If they should be near, try changing you `{0, -1.5}` in `Text` to smth like `{-2, 0}`. For me it is nice eniugh.

Comment: @Alx Thanks. It does look nicer. I just want the number to be above (outside) the circle and looks vertically aligned to the centre of the circle. Any "normal" looking way is fine. The thing is at the moment, when there are not many points, the numbers are rotated to much, I feel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Table[Graphics[{Circle[], 
    MapIndexed[{Red, PointSize -> Medium, Point @ #,  
       Black, Text[Style[#2[[1]], 14],  1.1 #, {Center, Center}]}&,
      Reverse @ CirclePoints[{0, 0}, {1, Pi/2}, n]]}, ImagePadding -> Scaled[.02]], 
   {n, 7, 10}] 

Row[%, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
cycleGraph = CycleGraph[#, 
    ##2,
    VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, "Circular"], 
    EdgeStyle -> Opacity[0],
    VertexStyle -> Red, 
    Prolog -> Circle[], 
    ImagePadding -> 15] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[cycleGraph[#, ImageSize -> Small, VertexLabelStyle -> 16] & /@ 
  Range[7, 10], 
  Spacer[10]]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Is `VertexLabelStyle -> 16` documented? I found nothing [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexLabelStyle.html?q=VertexLabelStyle).

Comment: @user64494,  it is not mentioned explicitly in the relevant docs pages. The first and last bullets in [VertexLabelStyle  > Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexLabelStyle.html)  _suggest_ why it works; an explicit and direct example in the basic examples would be more useful, of course,